# How to filter $match equals to Isodate using aggregate query in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following Record in Mongo Database

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54a0d4c5bffabd6a179834eb"),
    "is_afternoon_scheduled" : true,
    "employee_id" : ObjectId("546f0a06c7555ae310ae925a"),
    "currDate" : ISODate("2014-12-28T18:30:00Z"),
    "modified_date" : ISODate("2014-12-29T04:12:53.677Z"),
    "modified_by" : ObjectId("541a9c223416b36f67cfbfe8"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "manager_schedule" : {
        "afternoon_schedule_details" : {
            "event" : ObjectId("54507897cecff53914c82b6d"),
            "is_afternoon_scheduled" : true
        },
        "modified_by" : ObjectId("541a9c223416b36f67cfbfe8"),
        "modified_date" : ISODate("2014-12-29T04:13:00.432Z")
    }
}
```

I would like to Filter aggregate with $match equals to currDate. i am using the below query in mongoose but i didn't get any result with query. something is wrong with method or query. but when i run this query directly in mongodb i get the correct result. Need help in this.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var empid = mongoose.Types.ObjectId("54a0d4c5bffabd6a179834eb");

    Availability.aggregate() 
        .match( { employee_id : empid, currDate: "2014-12-28T18:30:00Z" } )
        .group({_id : "$employee_id",count: { $sum: 1 }})
        .exec(function (err, response) {
            if (err) console.log(err);
                res.json({"message": "success", "data": response, "status_code": "200"});
            }
    );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this:

```
currDate: new Date("2014-12-28T18:30:00Z")
```